# Append to file names in folder

Tags: r, regex

How to append filenames in a folder

```
Filenames: 
abc.wav
wjejrt.wav
13567tin.wav

Desired Output
abc_ENG.wav
wjejrt_ENG.wav
13567tin_ENG.wav
```

Tried this line code below but getting an error, maybe because I don't know the right use of file.rename function. Please help...

```
file.rename(list.files(pattern="*.wav"), paste0("_ENG"))
```

Comment: why do you spam tag a python tag here? it's only an r question...

Comment: use this `.*(?=\.wav)`

Comment: maybe `paste0(list.files(pattern="*.wav"), "_ENG")`

Comment: @U9-Forward only to check if there is any easier function available in Python to do the same...

Comment: this question is not related to python why added python tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base `R`you can do:

```
Filenames <- c("abc.wav", "wjejrt.wav", "13567tin.wav")
Fnames_new <- sub(".wav", "_ENG.wav", Filenames, fixed = TRUE)
file.rename(Filenames, Fnames_new)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged Python, you could use [`os.rename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) to rename your files:

```
from os import rename
from os import listdir
from os.path import splitext

# Current directory script is being run in
# You can change this to any path you want
path_to_folder = "."

for f in listdir(path_to_folder):
    if f.endswith(".wav"):
        name, ext = splitext(f)
        rename(f, name + "_ENG" + ext)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this one**

```
^.*(?=\\.wav)
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `.*` - Match anything except new line.
- `(?=\\.wav)` - Positive look ahead matches `.wav`.

**Change your code to this**

```
file.rename(list.files(pattern=".*(?=\\.wav)"), paste0("_ENG"))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wjuEtB/2/)

Comment: Thanks but I am getting this error: Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "".*(?=\."

Comment: @scorpionz use '\\'. it's problem of escaping. escape it properly